# JSS <ThemeProvider>, how to use media queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, jss

I am trying to use  to define some default colors that I want to use within my child components. The problem is that I also want to be able to set those colors according to media queries. For example:

```
const theme = {
  "@media (prefers-color-scheme: no preference)": {
    colorPrimary: "black",
  },
  "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)": {
    colorPrimary: "white",
  },
  "@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)": {
    colorPrimary: "black",
  },
  spacing: (s) => s * 5,
}
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to add it in createUseStyles and use it as props to ThemeProvider with no avail.

How can I use media queries with ThemeProvider?

This is my main App:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createUseStyles, ThemeProvider } from 'react-jss'
import { Header } from './components/header/Header';

const theme = {
  "@media (prefers-color-scheme: no preference)": {
    colorPrimary: "yellow",
  },
  "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)": {
    colorPrimary: "yellow",
  },
  "@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)": {
    colorPrimary: "yellow",
  },
  spacing: (s) => s * 5,
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <header>
          <Header>
            Hello
          </Header>
        </header>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {createUseStyles, useTheme} from 'react-jss'

const useStyles = createUseStyles(theme => ({
  header: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    color: theme.colorPrimary,
  },
}))

export const Header = ({children}) => {

  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles({...theme});

  return (
    <div className={classes.header}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

Header.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) for this:

```
const useDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches

const theme = {
  background: useDark ? 'black' : 'white',
  colorPrimary: useDark ? 'white' : 'black',

  spacing: s => s * 5,
}

// ...
```